# Search Panel List Box Selection --

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, listbox

I am using `WPF`. I added a search box which shows searched results in a `ListBox`. I want that as i click on a value display in listbox a new window should get open in its response to show its name. How is it possible? For Example: In this attached image if I click on assignment7 a new window should open to show its value assignment7. Can you answer my this question please.

[Full size image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfRD7.png)
[image]

Comment: It looks like the `datagridview`, not the `listbox`

Answer (score 0):

Try use OnSelected event, from event arguments get the index of selected list item, using this index get the selected item. 
Then make new window with title.

```
var newW  = new NewWindow();
newW.WindowTitle = "Title"; 
newW.Show();
```